# Http Requests are notworking after build apk [ionic 5]

Tags: ionic-framework, laravel-5, https, ionic5

I have developed a app using ionic 5.
http requests are working fine in browser. But not working after build apk.
it shows this error message

```
[ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(960)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -202
```

i have code like this:

```
getCategories(){
return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
  this.http.get(`${environment.apiUrl}/categories/list`).subscribe((res:any)=>{
    resolve(res);
  },(err)=>{
    reject(err);
  })
})
```

}

Please help me to fix this issue.

Comment: If you use the Angular HttpClient, why do you wrap the Observable into a Promise ?

Answer (score 1):

Google has updated their policy after android 8. After android 8 it will not allow you to use the HTTP as a api call you will have to use HTTPS in case you want to use.

Please see the below link this may help.

https://medium.com/@mountainappstudio/api-not-running-on-android-oreo-8-0-or-higher-version-problem-solved-ded5cc614d5e

Answer (score 0):

`network_security_config.xml` add this file in `resources/android/xml/` folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <domain>your domain</domain>
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">localhost</domain>
    </domain-config>
    <base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <trust-anchors>
            <certificates src="system" />
        </trust-anchors>
    </base-config>
</network-security-config>
```

`Add below code in config.xml`

```
<edit-config file="app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml" mode="merge" target="/manifest/application" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
            <application android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config" />
        </edit-config>
        <resource-file src="resources/android/xml/network_security_config.xml" target="app/src/main/res/xml/network_security_config.xml" />
```